# Is there a way to enter touchmode programatically?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

So I have an interesting problem. I have a ListView that I want to maintain the exact row selection and yoffset on an orientation change. As such I call:

```
list.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            list.requestFocusFromTouch();
            list.setSelectionFromTop(finalPosition, yoffset);
        }
    },100);
```

Seems pretty straightforward and it works well. The problem is that when I change the orientation twice (get back to the original orientation, ie landscape->portrait->landscape) than the list has exited TouchMode, ie list.isInTouchMode() returns false (On the first orientation change, list.isInTouchMode() returns true and everything is great, clicking works etc). As such when you scroll the listview programatically using setSelectionFromTop() and click on an item in the list without touching somewhere else in the app first, the list jumps and scrolls to where I clicked, highlighting the wrong item. It's very annoying and I can't seem to find a fix for it. Any ideas and suggestions are most welcome.

Calling list.requestFocusFromTouch() seems to have no effect on setting TouchMode.

More info:
[Android:To set an item as selected when the ListView opens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888015/androidto-set-an-item-as-selected-when-the-listview-opens)

I found a post from Romain Guy "Whenever you touch the screen, anywhere in the phone, you enter touch
mode for all of the applications. This is the desired and expected
behavior. " http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/590b02939d14675b/077ad77e4217e56e?lnk=gst&q=[android]+scroll+listview+not+in+touchmode#077ad77e4217e56e

All i want to do is somehow get into TouchMode without forcing the user to actually touch the device on the second orientation change. I have tried list.dispatchTouchEvent() multiple times. Its possible I am sending the wrong motion events:

```
list.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN , 
    list.getWidth(), list.getHeight(), 0));
list.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE , 
    list.getWidth(), list.getHeight(), 0));
list.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 
    list.getWidth(), list.getHeight(), 0));
```

Another option would be to figure out why we are no longer in TouchMode. I have not overriden onConfigurationChanged() so the layout is completely rebuilt on each orientation change.

Thanks in advance!

Jared

Comment: Btw I apologize for the ugly spacing of the code I submitted. Stackoverflow has a weird formatting restriction. - I managed to fix the spacing issues. It looks normaler now. =)

Comment: Just to be clear, is your listview set to use CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE so it can retain the most recently selected item?

Comment: It is, but on orientation change the entire view is recreated. I have tried changing the choice mode to every possible option without effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setItemChecked(...) method of the Listview. I've seen that used a fair bit when the Listview is set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, as that mode really makes each listview item a checkable object.

Also look at the following QA where someone was trying to do something similar. It appears that the easiest solution was to create a different background for 'checked' items.

[Android listview array adapter selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104966/android-listview-array-adapter-selected)

Comment: Unfort that doesnt seem to have any effect. I am not trying to change the background of the selected items, I want normal clicking behavior. IE I display a list, a list item is clicked on, the listitem selector background is displayed on the correct item and I handle the click. The problem is that on the second orientation change the list thinks it is still at the default location (selected item 0) even though it has been scrolled to some other position. So when I click on any item in the list the list jumps though the click is handled by the correct list item.